# How to integrate this function?

Tags: integration

Evaluate
$$\int\sqrt{x^3+x^2}\;dx$$

---

**What I have tried**

Using substitution (which I believe was applied incorrectly) I get:
$$\frac{(x+2)\sqrt{4x+4}}{4x+4}$$

How can this integral be evaluated?

Comment: Write the integrand as $x\sqrt{x+1}$ and substitute $u = \sqrt{x+1}$

Comment: The Maple command $$Student[Calculus1]:-IntTutor(sqrt(x^3+x^2), x)  $$ produces the answer $$2/5\, \left( x+1 \right) ^{5/2}-2/3\, \left( x+1 \right) ^{3/2}  $$ step by step with explanation. See that [link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) for info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first integral, suppose that $x\gt 0$. Let $u^2=1+x$. Then 
$$\sqrt{x^3+x^2}=x\sqrt{1+x}=(u^2-1)(u).$$
Since $2u\,du=dx$, we end up with the integral
$$\int (2u)(u^2-1)(u) \,du,$$
which is easy.

Comment: Andre Nicolas: WOW you are almost 200K!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\sqrt{\vphantom{\Large A}x^{3} + x^{2}\,}
=
\int\left[%
\left(x + 1\right)^{3/2} - \left(x + 1\right)^{1/2}
\right]
=
{2 \over 5}\,\left(x + 1\right)^{5/2} - {2 \over 3}\,\left(x + 1\right)^{3/2}
+
\mbox{constant}
$$